# After using ffmpeg to remove some streams in mkv file, it takes much longer to open the media file in potplayer in Windows

Tags: ffmpeg

It is well known that ffmpeg command line can be used to remove some streams in mkv or mp4 files, and I have no problem in doing so.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -map 0 -map -0:a:3 -map -0:a:6 -c copy output.mp4
```

The only issue I meet sometimes is, the result media files in mkv or mp4 are much much slower to be opened by player. I cannot figure out the real reason and bypass it.

Any hint or help on solving this issue? Thanks!